# Redesign of header on SE sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

Stack Overflow, as we know, switched to a new header design. When will redesigned header be avaliable for all Q/As?

Comment: What?  I'm not the only one who thinks that the new header height is excessive.  Why was my comment unacceptable?

Comment: I did a bit of *literal* A/B comparison testing and its not actually that much bigger https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqpPi.gif

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not only is it not bigger, it's actually significantly smaller, because it combines the two navbars into one.

Answer (score 15):

We don't have a definite timeline for rollout to the rest of the network.

The plan is to first roll this out to the internationalized Stack Overflow sites ([Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)).

After those, we would be migrating the different designed sites - each of these has a different look, so we need to make sure the header design fits them.

We have also not decided yet what form the rollout will take - we may end up just tweaking the current headers to bring them in line with the Stack Overflow header.

Comment: On SO/MSO the site "header" (like what's blue here on MSE) disappears.  On those sites that doesn't really take anything away, but I would hate to lose the beautiful headers on some of our other sites like [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/).  On sites with art, the approach of just folding the logo into the top bar wouldn't work.

Comment: @Oded: Same background art would be used on WorldBuilding's header.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I can't speak to that - the designers will deal with each design on a case by case basis.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney the Worldbuilding header art is much taller than the new SO top bar.  Neither slicing out most of the art nor making the top bar humongous would be suitable.  We [love our art](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3551/28) and do not want to lose it!

Comment: @MonicaCello: WB logo, in its current design, fits in new SE header design. The background will continue on the sides normally.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney click through and look.  I'm talking about the *header art*.  Several sites have meaningful art in that space.  I'm not talking about the *logo*.

Comment: Bannerified background art.

Comment: I like, sort of, the SO SE top bar. Couple things seem "wonky," however. The "hamburger" style menu icon feels totally wrong at top-right. Considering its size, and resemblance to a mobile-style menu, it feels better where it was, top-left. Search box in center seems wrong too. Might be better as an icon that balloons like the inbox, etc. does, and placed top-right. Both places are where many people are now trained to look for them (old-school folks aside). Using the search icon increases banner space so you can return "Badges", "Unanswered", Ask Question", and "Help" to the nav bar.